# Getting errors while executing the string operation

Tags: sql-server

I am having problem with the execution of the following code in sql server 2016

```
select SUBSTRING ('email', CHARINDEX ('@', 'email') + 1, LEN ('email')-CHARINDEX ('@', 'email')) 
count (email)
from income
```

its saying expecting '(' or select near the email in the last line. I also tried in 'email'

Comment: Do note that if you are trying to get the remainder of the email address after the @, the calculations are unnecessary. If the length parameter of a SUBSTRING is greater than the remaining number of characters in the target string, SUBSTRING returns the remainder of the string. So `SUBSTRING (email, CHARINDEX ('@', email) + 1, LEN (email))` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma... after your first column selection which is your SUBSTRING function. I also added a column name... and the group by that will be needed. Also, you probably don't want the substring of the actual *text* of email, but rather the column email so i removed the quotes.

```
select 
SUBSTRING (email, CHARINDEX ('@', email) + 1, LEN (email)-CHARINDEX ('@', email)) as DerrivedColumn, --comma added here, removed quotes, aliased column
count(email) as EmailCount --added column alias
from income
group by
SUBSTRING ('email', CHARINDEX ('@', 'email') + 1, LEN ('email')-CHARINDEX ('@', 'email'))
```